# randomly select elements from given array imported from database

Tags: random

```
$rr=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM personalinfoo");

while($ss=mysql_fetch_array($rr))
{

echo $ss[g];

echo "<br/>";
}
```

from above data from database i have to print any two data randomly!!

Comment: Please add language tag(s). Looks a bit phpish to me, but you shouldn't be forcing people who may be able to help you to *guess*.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the random ids directly from database instead of fetching all of them and select random ids. Change the SQL to

```
SELECT id FROM personalinfoo order by rand() limit 2
```